# Location section on careers.stackoverflow.com could use exclusion areas too

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page, location

I could use an option for "I do NOT want to work at this location" in the careers CV. Essentially I'm willing to relocate, but there are several areas where I cannot or am reluctant to relocate to. (For instance, my pet ferrets are illegal in California.) So, basically, I would to be able to say "anywhere in the US, *except* locations A, B, and C."

As it is, I have to leave the locations pretty much wide open and decline employers manually. That's going to cost both them and me needless time.

Location preferences or ranking would be a nice idea as well. For instance, "location X is my first choice, and Y second, but I'll accept M, N, or O, and am not willing to work in Q."

A free-text field to supplement the structured location entries might address much of this simply.